# How can one Tcl thread cause an event in another?

Tags: multithreading, events, tcl

I have a system with multiple I/O interfaces, and I'm collecting the output of all of them into a common log.  Two of the interfaces are through well-behaved channels that are opened as file-like objects, and can be managed on an event basis with "fileevent readable".  The other two are the problem.

These are to a vendor-supplied library, which someone else has already kindly wrapped into a Tcl package (snoopy, FWIW).  However, the only read access is a blocking call, and there's nothing in the package that would cause an event equivalent to a fileevent.

I've figured out how to spawn a separate thread to block on the read, pull the result, and put it into a message queue for the main thread.  But having the main thread block on reading the queue would seem to defeat the purpose, especially since there are two queues it would have to block on.  And I haven't been able to get the reader to generate an event that can trigger the main thread to read the queue.

I've looked on the tcl.tk wiki to no avail so far.  I've tried using the uevent library to generate an event on a message push, but the event goes to the writing thread instead of the reading thread, which really doesn't help.  It seems like there should be some solution related to a Thread condition variable, but so far I haven't been able to find an appropriate design pattern for that use of the library.

If all else fails I'll fall back to a Tk event, but I'm trying to keep Tk out of this as it's meant to be an automated system with no GUI, and any mention of Tk pushes tclsh into wish and pops up a GUI window.

I feel like I'm close, but just missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, the main thread needs to run the event loop in order to receive events. The idiomatic way to do this is to use `vwait forever` once you've finished setting up your program (I assume you're not going to write to that variable) but if you are running Tk you already have an event loop (GUIs *need* event loops).

There are two ways to do the messaging between threads.

### Thread events

The [`thread::send`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/27327) command uses events to dispatch code to execute (the message) between threads. All you need to do is to tell the worker thread what the main thread's ID is so it knows where to send to. Note that you may well want to send the event asynchronously, like this:

```
thread::send -async $mainID [list eventReceiver "something happened" $payload]
```

### Pipelines

If you're using Tcl 8.6, you can use [`chan pipe`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/chan.htm#M29) to create an unnamed OS pipeline. You can then use normal fileevents, etc., to deliver information from thread to another that way.

```
# In master
lassign [chan pipe] readSide writeSide
thread::transfer $worker $readSide
thread::send $worker [list variable pipe $readSide]
fconfigure $writeSide -blocking 0
fileevent $writeSide readable [list handleLine $writeSide]

# In worker
fconfigure $pipe -blocking 0 -buffering line
puts $pipe "got event: $payload"
```

It's probably easier to use thread events in retrospect! (The main advantage of a pipe is that you can also put the worker in another process if necessary.)

Comment: Thread events are what I'm trying to use, but I can't use thread::send - the data is coming *out* of the reader thread, not going in for processing.  The chan pipe looks promising - I'll look into that immediately.

Comment: Sadly, there's a fatal issue with [chan pipe] - it's only available in 8.6(beta), and I'm working on medical equipment.  We do *not* use betas, even for test scripting.  Is there any other common construction of event-driven cross-thread data exchange?  I'm realizing that my initial problem was the choice of a queue rather than a channel to pass data, and the proper choice there will make this task practical.

Comment: I've finally grokked the right way to use thread::send to send back up to the master thread.  I'll post my solution as an answer for others to see in a bit.

Comment: @Erik: I understand totally about avoiding betas, and for almost everything I do I'm very conservative. (Heck, I've still got some production code running with **8.0** because I can't justify updating.) That's why I gave it as a second alternative. It's also possible to synthesize a pipe (on Unix only) with the help of an external `cat` pipeline, but that's gross.

Comment: ... and why is it an advantage to work in a different process?  'Turns out there are several reasons, including that it can be easier to give that process an otherwise-available core, AND that it might GREATLY simplify testing/maintenance/deployment/...

Answer (score 2):

I finally grokked what Donal was saying about Thread events.  I blame inadequate morning caffeine for not getting it the first time.

All the prior examples of thread::send I've seen concerned a master sending scripts down to the worker thread.  In this case, the worker thread needs to send scripts back up to the master, where the script is the one that would be called on [fileevent readable] if this was a channel.

Here's my test code for the interaction:

```
proc reader {payload} {
    puts $payload
}

set t1 [thread::create]
thread::send -async $t1 {
    proc produce {parentid} {
        while 1 {
            after 250   ;# substitutes for
            incr data   ;# the blocking read
            thread::send $parentid "reader $data"
        }
    }
}

set tid [thread::id]
thread::send -async $t1 [list produce $tid]

vwait forever
```

The part I saw but didn't immediately grok was the importance of the master thread having an ID that can be sent to the worker.  The key that I'd missed was that the worker can send scripts to the master just as easily as the master can send scripts to the worker; the worker just usually doesn't know the master's Thread ID.

Once the ID is passed to it, the producer thread can therefore use thread::send to call a proc in the master to handle the data, and it becomes an event in the master thread, just as I'd desired.  It's not the way I've worked with threads in the past, but once understood it's powerful.