# Inserting text to text box in tcl tk through thread

Tags: multithreading, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm currently developing gui in  tcl tk. In the gui I am trying to read file continuously as like (tail -f).I want to put data in to text box. I have created thread for separating this taks and keep gui alive. But It don't allow me to use  text widget name inside the thread.

So I'm stuck with the question how to pass text widget name to the thread.

```
ttk::notebook .note -width 1000 -height 450
ttk::frame .note.tabOne; 
ttk::frame .note.tabTwo; 

.note add .note.tabOne -text "Test Configuration" 
.note add .note.tabTwo -text "Results"

set .note.tabTwo.results [ScrolledWindow .note.tabTwo.results ]
pack .note.tabTwo.results -fill both -expand true

set resulttxt [text .note.tabTwo.results.resulttxt -wrap none -width 63 -height 10]
.note.tabTwo.results setwidget $resulttxt
pack .note

proc displayText {$file} { 
    global file
    global resulttxt
    set data "hithi fio ui"
    $resulttxt insert end $data
    exec fio $file --status-interval=1 > test1.txt 2>&1 &

    set t [thread::create]
    thread::send -async $t [list set yourxs $resulttxt]

    thread::send $t {
    global resulttxt
    puts $yourxs
    # Load the Tcllib fileutil package to use its
    # findByPattern procedure.
    #package require fileutil
    #set files [fileutil::findByPattern [pwd] *.tcl]
    set log [open /media/sf_Tcl/bin/project/fio_ui-1.0/test1.txt r]

    for { } { true } { after 1000 } {
        #after [expr { int(500*rand()) }]
        $yourxs insert end  $data1

    }

    close $log
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436048/how-can-one-tcl-thread-cause-an-event-in-another ?

Answer (score 0):

In Tcl, *all* command names (including all widget names) are local to a particular interpreter instance, and instances are bound to a thread. The non-GUI thread will have to send code to the GUI thread to do the insert. The easiest way to handle this is to make the GUI thread create a command in the non-GUI thread to do the insertion.

```
thread::send $t [list proc appendToTextWidget string \
        "thread::send [thread::id] .note.tabTwo.results.resulttxt end \$string"]
```

The quoting required is a little tricky, since you can't just use `list` to do all the work, but it is fairly straight forward since `thread::id` is guaranteed to return a metacharacter-free word.

Once you've done that, the non-GUI thread can just do:

```
appendToTextWidget "here's a message\n"
```

and that will add the text at the end, concealing all the details of how that happens from the processing code.