# How to write to file without opening it

Tags: tcl

Is there anyway in TCL to create a file and write to it, without opening and closing it? This is how I'm doing it right now:

```
set resultFile [open "$logFile.log" w]  

puts $resultFile $data

close $resultFile
```

I'm asking this because I have to perform this operation numerous times and it will  help in runtime if I can just pipe the data to the file directly.

Comment: Short answer , "no", you have to open the file before you write to it.  But that doesn't mean you have to open/write/close it every time.  You should be able to hold the file open while your program runs.

Comment: Extended answer, if it is about decoupling (in terms of process synchronicity) your main program from (excessive, non-critical, ...) I/O delays, you may want to factor out actual logging as a background task. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436048/how-can-one-tcl-thread-cause-an-event-in-another for two options. The background worker would then manage the file handle (`open`, `close`) and actually write to the file (`puts`), whenever a logging event arrives from the main program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanism for writing to a file requires that it be open. You are correct that repeatedly opening a file can be slow when done in a loop (though, the loop has to be pretty big to notice it).

You don't have to open it before each call to `puts`,  however. You can open it once at the start of your program and keep it open while the program runs.

Comment: @Ken, also consider opening the file using the [`a` access mode](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm#M9).

Comment: It should be noted that if the program writing such a log file is a daemon, it should have facilities to make its log file rotated by tools such as `logrotate`. It usually suffices to trap a dedicated signal (such as `SIGHUP`) and reopen the log file when one is received.